# Is there an analog to 'gcloud projects list' in the Google Cloud Platform REST API?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

Which Google Cloud Platform (GCP) REST API route would I use for listing GCP projects?

I.e., which GCP REST API route would give a response similar to the output of the `list` Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) command:

```sh
gcloud projects list

#=>

PROJECT_ID     NAME           PROJECT_NUMBER
. . .          . . .          . . .
```

Comment: If you know which gcloud command makes an api call you are interested, you can use '--log-http'  flag which will display all api calls and responses made by the command.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to enable the "Cloud Resource Manager API" [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com?project=bennie-devops)
2. Use `google.cloudresourcemanager('v1').projects.list`:

   ```sh
   curl \
   --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
   --location \
   --request GET \
   "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects"

   #=>

   {
     "projects": [
       . . .
     ]
   }
   ```